# Javascript difference between numbers in the same field

Tags: javascript, function, extjs

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the difference between 2 numbers (24h time) within the same field

```
{
  xtype: "textfield",
  fieldLabel: "Monday",
  name: "mon1"
}, {
  xtype: "numberfield",
  fieldLabel: "Hours",
  name: "hoursMon1",
}
```

Basically the user input would look something like this as an example:

```
mon1 = 7.15-16.45
```

Then I'd need a function to calculate the difference (i.e "9.30") into the `hoursMon1` field.

Due to how the program works I can't just split the input into 2 fields and compare the difference, so is there any way I can do something similar from just 1 field?

Comment: If the string the user inputs always looks something like `7.15-16.45`, you can use the string.split function, `input.split('-')`, to get an array like `[7.15, 16.45]` and then calculate the difference from there

Comment: `Due to how the program works I can't just split the input into 2 fields` how the program works? why you cannot?

Comment: @AZ_ Basically there's a connected database which requires the input in this particular field to be in a certain format i.e both "start" and "end" time.

Comment: @TKoL Thank you! I somehow forgot the split function existed.

Answer (score 0):

Get time difference in console.log function

```
var time = "7.15-16.45".split("-");
console.log(msToTime(getMillsec(time[1])- getMillsec(time[0])))  //output 09-30


//get milliseconds
function getMillsec(ctime){
      var timeParts = ctime.split(".");
        return ((+timeParts[0] * (60000 * 60)) + (+timeParts[1] * 60000));
}

//convert millisecond to hour:min format
function msToTime(duration) {
    var milliseconds = parseInt((duration%1000)/100)
        , seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
        , minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
        , hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24);

    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    return hours + "-" + minutes;
}
```